# clicking a button in javascript without button id

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am attempting to automate a button click on a website. The only problem is, the HTML for the button looks like this (please note that this is not the exact button I am trying to click, it is just a real example of what a lot of buttons look like):

```
<button type="submit" class="Ghost-btn">Continue</button>
```

Obviously, there is no ID for this button, so I don't know how to 'click' on it. Is there a way of using the class name, or is there a way to program javascript to edit the HTML and add an ID for the button?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Louis

PS the link for the above button is https://raffle.sneakersnstuff.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-700-salt-EG7487 , and it is the first button you will see, labelled 'continue'.

Comment: If it's the first button, you could just get all buttons and work with the first element of that array

Comment: `document.querySelector('.Ghost-btn').click()` is what you want.

Comment: The answers here are correct, but for even greate precision, you can select the button in the developer tools of your browser and choose something like "copy css selector", which will give you a longer and unique selector for that element (probably something > something > something .Ghost-btn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to use **any CSS selector** to select an element in JS, for example:

```
document.querySelector(".Ghost-btn").click();
```

Read more about this at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

---

This would also allow you to select the button in other ways, for instance:

```
document.querySelector("button[type=\"submit\"]").click();
```

is also valid.

Comment: Thank you for that, it did work. I had tried this, but without the '.' before the class name. Just out of interest, how would you go about clicking a 'size' button on the page, as they do not have seperate class names. <span class="Size">US 4</span> is the code for one of the sizes. The same thing applies to the code for selecting the different countries: <div class="SizeConversion">UK</div> 
Is there a way to click the buttons using their names? Is tht what tag names are?
Thanks again
Louis

Comment: So, if you used the same code (e.g. `document.querySelector(".Size")`) it would **always** select the **first** occurrence of that element. If, say, you always wanted the 6th occurrence, you could use `document.querySelector(".Size:nth-child(6)")`. Otherwise, you could use `document.querySelectorAll(".Size")` to get every element with the `Size` class, and then loop through each of them and select one logically - e.g. by looking at its text contents, etc.

Comment: How do you make it select a size based on its text content? Eg 4

Comment: @Louis Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xr6egkyL/1/. The magic all happens in the `getByContents` function, the rest is for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

ID is just a handy and simple way for identifying any DOM element.
You can use other attribute or a set of attributes unique to the document for this purpose.

For example "type" in your example, if this is the only input of type "submit"
Or if there are more than one "submit" buttons, you can use `type="submit"` and `class="Ghost-btn"` or even text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- document.getElementsByClassName("Ghost-btn");
- document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTTON");

but be sure that there might be more than one components so have to select the right one.